# how to switch language by toggle button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have tried to switch the language from `eng` to `Japenese` by using toggle button.but it doesn't work. kindly help to suggest on it. here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node.js app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
            <div class="slider round">
                <span language='japanese' class="on">JPN</span>
                <span language='english' class="off">ENG</span>
            </div>
        </label>
        <ul class="nav-items">
    <style>
    .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 34px;
    }

    .switch input {
    display: none;
    }

    .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ca2222;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    }

    .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    }

    input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2ab934;
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
    transform: translateX(55px);
    }

    /*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
    .on {
    display: none;
    }

    .on, .off {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    input:checked + .slider .on {
    display: block;
    }

    input:checked + .slider .off {
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class="title">Hello World</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
        const sliderEl = document.querySelector('.slider');
        const link = document.querySelectorAll('span');
        const titleEl = document.querySelector('.title');
        const descrEl = document.querySelector('.description');

        link.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                sliderEl.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
                el.classList.add('active');

                const attr = el.getAttribute('language');

                titleEl.textContent = data[attr].title;
                descrEl.textContent = data[attr].description;
            });
        });

        var data = {
            "english":
            {
                "title": "Hello World"

            },
            "japanese":
            {
                "title": "ハロー・ワールド"

            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit. I putted an event listener on the `input` event of the checkbox and change the text content to the corresponding language based on the fact if the checkbox is checked or not.

The active class didn't do anything in your example so I removed that.

The `currentTarget` property of the event object will get you the element that the event handler is attached too. This is used to see if the checkbox is checked or not.

```js
document.querySelector('#togBtn').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  document.querySelector('.title').textContent = data[event.currentTarget.checked ? 'japanese' : 'english'].title;
});

var data = {
  "english": {
    "title": "Hello World"
  },
  "japanese": {
    "title": "ハロー・ワールド"
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
  <div class="slider round">
    <span language='japanese' class="on">JPN</span>
    <span language='english' class="off">ENG</span>
  </div>
</label>

<ul class="nav-items">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Hello World</h2>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            
          if (checkbox.checked) {
            // do this
            console.log('Checked');
          } else {
            // do that
            console.log('Not checked' );
          }
        });
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/au3rvcwh/44/

You can use it to detect checkbox is checked or not and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to add the `?` in this statement `sliderEl.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');`

the next problem is, this line `//  descrEl.innerText = data[attr].description;` because there is no description attribute in the object.

```
        "english":
        {
            "title": "Hello World"

        },
```

and i would use `innerText` here `titleEl.innerText = data[attr].title;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node.js app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
        <div class="slider round">
            <span language='japanese' class="on">JPN</span>
            <span language='english' class="off">ENG</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <ul class="nav-items">
<style>
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 90px;
height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
display: none;
}

.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ca2222;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
-ms-transform: translateX(55px);
transform: translateX(55px);
}

/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
.on {
display: none;
}

.on, .off {
color: white;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
font-size: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked + .slider .on {
display: block;
}

input:checked + .slider .off {
display: none;
}
</style>
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Hello World</h2>
</div>
<script>
    const sliderEl = document.querySelector('.slider');
    const link = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    const titleEl = document.querySelector('.title');
    const descrEl = document.querySelector('.description');

    link.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            sliderEl.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
            el.classList.add('active');

            const attr = el.getAttribute('language');
            titleEl.innerText = data[attr].title;
          //  descrEl.innerText = data[attr].description;
        });
    });

    var data = {
        "english":
        {
            "title": "Hello World"

        },
        "japanese":
        {
            "title": "ハロー・ワールド"

        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```